# Docker/C++ problem - Compiling Error /usr/bin/ld: cannot open output file server: Is a directory

Tags: c++, docker, makefile

I'm trying to compile a C++ program using cmake in ubuntu containerized in Docker. Without Docker I can make it work just fine, but with it I seem to get some errors, whowever I can't seem to fix them :/

I've tried resolving to change the path to many different combinations in the hopes that I was just writing in the wrong path.

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04

# Set the working directory to /app
WORKDIR /app

# Copy the current directory contents into the container at /app
COPY . /app

# Install any needed packages specified in the requirements.txt
RUN apt-get update && apt-get -y install g++ make cmake-curses-gui libsqlite3-dev libmariadb-client-lgpl-dev subversion

# Make port 8078 available to the world outside this container
EXPOSE 8078

# Retrieve EOServ and build it
RUN svn checkout svn://eoserv.net/eoserv/trunk/ /app/eoserv
RUN cd /app/eoserv && mkdir build && cd build
RUN cmake -G "Unix Makefiles" /app/eoserv
RUN make

# Run ./eoserv when the container launches
RUN /app/eoserv/eoserv
# Here I've tried several options like
# RUN ./eoserv
# RUN cd /app/eoserv && ./eoserv
```

Expected results would be an eoserv binary in desired folder, it works when I don't run it in the docker image, but cmake it all by itself, without Docker.
Actual results are:

```
[ 91%] Building C object CMakeFiles/eoserv.dir/tu/sha256.c.o
[100%] Linking CXX executable eoserv
/usr/bin/ld: cannot open output file eoserv: Is a directory
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
CMakeFiles/eoserv.dir/build.make:305: recipe for target 'eoserv' failed
make[2]: *** [eoserv] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:67: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/eoserv.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/eoserv.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:127: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
The command '/bin/sh -c make' returned a non-zero code: 2
```

Answer (score 2):

The [`RUN`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#run) instruction starts a new shell. So the commands you `RUN` previously will only be local to that shell, which includes things like `cd`, and the next `RUN` instruction will start a new shell without knowledge of the previous.

The instructions

```
RUN cd /app/eoserv && mkdir build && cd build
RUN cmake -G "Unix Makefiles" /app/eoserv
RUN make
```

needs to be combined into a *single* `RUN` instruction

```
RUN cd /app/eoserv && mkdir build && cd build && cmake -G "Unix Makefiles" /app/eoserv && make
```

You could of course write a script which runs the commands, and invoke that script with the `RUN` instruction.

Comment: Thanks that fixed something at least, however, now I'm getting this error:

`Step 9/9 : RUN cd /app/eoserv && ./eoserv`
`Running in 6f4e36529644`
`/bin/sh: 1: ./eoserv: not found`
`The command '/bin/sh -c cd /app/eoserv && ./eoserv' returned a non-zero code: 127`

Comment: @MatiasPersson Unfortunately no. You might want to post a new question about that issue.

Comment: Thanks, I asked the person beneath me before asking new question on the site :)

Comment: @MatiasPersson Please remember that this site isn't only for you, it's for everyone who might have similar problems. By posting a brand new question it will be easier for other to find it and the possible solution.

Comment: That's true. I'll try to ask a new question then, to see if I can get a response there.

Comment: For the error 127, it could not find the eoserv binary. You likely need to enter the `build` directory. `/bin/sh -c cd /apps/eoserv/build && ./eoserv`